# Custom delete button in uitableview cell don't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I made tableView with **filteredReservations** array wich contains Rezervacija objects.
I added custom button "board", and when button is clicked, I ask  with alert view to confirm this and then sending request to server. When receive server's response I need to delete row from table and object from filteredReservations array.
When I delete first row it's ok, but after that in filteredReservations instead of Rezervacija object, I got UIButton objects! I don't know HOW :)

**Code:**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return([filteredReservations count]);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    Reservation *reservation = [filteredReservations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *label = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ (%d)", reservation.name, reservation.seatsNumber];
    cell.textLabel.text = label;
    [label release];
    [reservation release];
    tableView.allowsSelection = FALSE;
    UIButton *cellButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [cellButton setFrame:CGRectMake(430.0, 2.0, 106.0, 40.0)];
    [cellButton setTitle:@"Board" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(BoardPassengers:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:cellButton];
        cellButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    return cell;
}


-(void)BoardPassengers:(id)sender{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Question" message:@"Do you want to board passengers?"
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Odustani" otherButtonTitles:@"Da", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    passengerForBoarding = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:((UIControl*)sender).tag inSection:1];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"cancel");
    }
    else
    {
        Reservation *reservationNew = [filteredReservations objectAtIndex:passengerForBoarding.row];
        NSString *reservationId = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",reservationNew.reservationId];

        params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"1", @"tour_id", @"1", @"bus_number",reservationId, @"reservation_id", nil];  
        [[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/service/boardingToBus.json" params:params delegate:self];
        [DSBezelActivityView newActivityViewForView:self.view withLabel:@"Boarding..."];
    }
}

- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse*)response {  

    if([[request resourcePath] isEqualToString:@"/service/boardingToBus.json"]){
        if([[response bodyAsString] isEqualToString:@"ERROR"]){
            [DSBezelActivityView removeViewAnimated:YES];
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Error." 
                                                           delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }else{
            [DSBezelActivityView removeViewAnimated:YES];

            [filteredReservations removeObjectAtIndex:passengerForBoarding.row];
            [self.tableView reloadData];

            //[self.tableView beginUpdates];
            //[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:passengerForBoarding]
            //                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
           // NSLog(@"%i", passengerForBoarding.row);

            //[self.tableView endUpdates];

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to make sure the table view is explicitly aware of how many filtered reservations it needs to display.

```
// assuming only one section for your table view
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return([filteredReservations count]);
}
```

For more info:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mentioned all methods in code snipped. I already have the same method :|

Comment: You should get rid of the line that says "[reservation release]" in your tableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath method.  In that context, reservation is fetched, not created, and therefore should not be released at that point.  This *might* have something to do with the fact you're only seeing buttons in the table view, but no guarantees.  :-)

Comment: I will try this tomorrow when I get physical device :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can get the value of "Reservation ID" By this.

```
-(void)BoardPassengers:(id)sender{
    Reservation *reservationNew = [filteredReservations objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];
    NSString *reservationId = [NSString StringWithFormat:@"%d",reservationNew.reservationId];}
```

Or you can use this value anywhere you want like you have mentioned via alert-box.